# What would cause an abort signal to be sent to a Docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, signals

My web service is running in a Docker container.

Recently, I've seen many `SystemExit` errors which are raised because the server I use (`gunicorn`) receive the `abort` signal.

I've checked the `CPU Utilization` and `Memory Utilization` monitor, but both are normal, less than 50% utilization, which doesn't seem likely to be the reason.

Since I may do some download on request in my service, I'm wondering maybe it's caused by running out of file handlers, but I've never seen related exception raised in my log.

What other reasons may result in an `ABORT` signal?

Comment: What type of orchestration are you using? None, swarm, kubernetes, etc?

Comment: @Robert The orchestration is provided by the PAAS vendor, which I believe is using `swarm` under the hood.

Comment: That is a big point to see whether or not is the reason. In my case AWS-ECS is the vendor and under certain circumstances, containers are killed and started again (CPU or Memory limits, or because another essential container exits)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to debug soft/hard memory limits on the PAAS solution, also try to run strace or sysdig kind of utility to figure out the reason for exit.

Answer (score 0):

How are you starting the application inside the Container? You can use either the EXEC or SHELL form of starting your process when you mention inside Dockerfile using CMD or ENTRYPOINT. EXEC form will allow Docker to forward any signals to the running process so that you can handle it there. This would allow you to understand the specific reasons for your aborts.